# Invalid block tag on line 18: 'endblock'. Did you forget to register or load this tag? how to solve

Tags: python-2.7

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content }

<body>
<h1> Hello world !!!!!!! </h1>

</body>    

{% endblock  %}
```

Comment: how to run the above code without error or how to solve the above error

Comment: `{% block content }` should be `{% block content %}`